# Initializing an existing object

Tags: java, multithreading, object, global-variables

I am trying to initialize my paintcall global variable to a the ballGUI object that already exists. I have to do this to be able to call the repaint method in my run function for multithreadng so that a new GUI isnt made which each individual ball. Imports left out for space.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class BallT extends Thread implements Runnable {

  private static int xcord, ycord, ychange, xchange;
  private static boolean xUp;
  private static boolean yUp;
  private Color color;
  private BallGUI paintcall=//? existing object BallGUI ;

  public BallT(int x, int y) {
    yUp = false;
    xUp = false;
    xcord = x;
    ycord = y;
    color = new Color((int) Math.random(), (int) Math.random(),
        (int) Math.random());
  }

  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return xcord;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return ycord;
  }

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
      if (xUp == true) {
        xcord = xcord + xchange;
      } else {
        xcord = xcord - xchange;
      }
      if (yUp == true) {
        ycord = ycord + ychange;
      } else {
        ycord = ycord - ychange;
      }
      if (xcord <= 0) {
        xUp = true;
        xchange = (int) Math.random() * 5;
      } else if (xcord > 340) {
        xUp = false;
        xchange = (int) Math.random() * 5;
      }
      if (ycord <= 0) {
        yUp = true;
        ychange = (int) Math.random() * 5;
      } else if (ycord > 340) {
        yUp = false;
        ychange = (int) Math.random() * 5;
      }
      paintcall.repaint();
    }

  }

}



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BallGUI extends JFrame {

  public JPanel ballappear;
  private final int maxBalls = 20;
  private BallT[] balls;
  private int count;
  private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  public BallGUI() {
    super("Bouncing");
    ballappear = new JPanel();
    count = 0;
    balls = new BallT[20];
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        makeBall(e);
      }
    });
    add(ballappear);

  }

  private void makeBall(MouseEvent e) {
    if (count < maxBalls - 1) {
      int x = e.getX();
      int y = e.getY();
      balls[count] = new BallT(x, y);
      threadPool.execute(balls[count]);
      count++;
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillOval(balls[i].getX(), 340, 10, 10);
      g.setColor(balls[i].getColor());
      g.fillOval(balls[i].getX(), balls[i].getY(), 10, 10);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You'd need a constructor that took an instance of this class. And I don't see why you need it. If it's a global you can only have **one** ball.

Comment: One ball per thread, the issue lies with the repaint method repainting the new BallGUI rather than the existing one to which the ball exists on.

Comment: You must NOT subclass Thread if you don't want to implement a custom thread! Implementing Runnable is sufficient in your case!

Comment: @isnot2bad, subclassing Thread just to override its run() method is an old-fashioned and somewhat restrictive way of doing things, but it works in a lot of cases.  I would not say "you must not..." ('though, if you worked for me, I _would_ say "you _may_ not..."

Comment: @james I agree in general, but in this case, the thread-instance is handed over to an `ExecutorService`. So the instance is used as a `Runnable` which has nothing in common with `Thread` except that the latter implements the former. He could have subclassed `RenderableImageProducer` or `AsyncBoxView.ChildState` just as well as they also implement `Runnable`. A clear mistake in my point of view.

Comment: @isnot2bad, And I was completely oblivious to the fact that the example was creating Thread instances that are never .start()ed.  D'Oh!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the simple solution - change the BallT constructor to take a BallGUI instance:

```
public BallT(int x, int y, BallGUI ballGUI) {
    this.paintcall = ballGUI;
    yUp = false;
    //...
```

Next, pass in the instance during construction in the GUI object:

```
private void makeBall(MouseEvent e) {
    if (count < maxBalls - 1) {
        // ...
        balls[count] = new BallT(x, y, this);
    }
}
```

However, this is back to front according to good Model-View-Controller (MVC) design practice. Generally, the view (BallGUI) should know about the model (BallT) but the model should be ignorant of the view. Your BallGUI already maintains a list of BallT's which it presumably queries in the paint() method. I would consider having a Controller which had the responsibility for calling an updatePosition() method on each BallT in turn and then calling repaint() on the GUI. This would also have the advantage that you aren't creating a new Thread for each ball, but just need one controller thread.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. My bouncing balls work wonderfully now :)